# Providing Language FallBack In A SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that represents an `Object`. It has many columns but also fields that require language support.

For simplicity let's say I have 3 tables:

- MainObjectTable
- LanguageDependantField1
- LanguageDependantField2.

`MainObjectTable` has a PK int called `ID`, and both `LanguageDependantTables` have a foreign key link back to the `MainObjectTable` along with a language code and the date they were added.

I've created a stored procedure that accepts the MainObjectTable ID and a `Language`. It will return a single row containing the most recent items from the language tables. The select statement looks like

```
SELECT 
    MainObjectTable.VariousColumns, 
    LanguageDependantField1.Description, 
    LanguageDependantField2.SomeOtherText
FROM 
    MainObjectTable 
OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 LanguageDependantField1.Description
      FROM LanguageDependantField1
      WHERE LanguageDependantField1.MainObjectTable_ID = MainObjectTable.ID 
        AND LanguageDependantField1.Language_ID = @language
      ORDER BY 
         LanguageDependantField1.[Default], LanguageDependantField1.CreatedDate DESC) LanguageDependantField1
OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 LanguageDependantField2.SomeOtherText
      FROM LanguageDependantField2
      WHERE LanguageDependantField2.MainObjectTable_ID = MainObjectTable.ID 
        AND LanguageDependantField2.Language_ID = @language
      ORDER BY 
        LanguageDependantField2.[Default] DESC, LanguageDependantField2.CreatedDate DESC) LanguageDependantField2
WHERE 
     MainObjectTable.ID = @MainObjectTableID
```

What I want to add is the ability to fallback to a default language if a row isn't found in the specified language. Let's say we use "German" as the selected language. Is it possible to return an English row from `LanguageDependantField1` if the German does not exist presuming we have `@fallbackLanguageID`

Also am I right to use `OUTER APPLY` in this scenario or should I be using `JOIN`?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the use of `Outer Apply` is correct if you want to correlate the `MainObjectTable` table rows to the inner queries. You cannot use Joins with references in the derived table to the outer table. If you wanted to use Joins, you would need to include the joining column(s) and in this case pre-filter the results. Here is what that might look like:

```
With RankedLanguages As
    (
    Select LDF1.MainObjectTable_ID, LDF1.Language_ID, LDF1.Description, LDF1.SomeOtherText, ...
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By LDF1.MainObjectTable_ID, LDF1.Language_ID
                                Order By LDF1.[Default] Desc, LDF1.CreatedDate Desc ) As Rnk
    From LanguageDependantField1 As LDF1
    Where LDF1.Language_ID In( @languageId, @defaultLanguageId )
    )
Select M.VariousColumns
    ,  Coalesce( SpecificLDF.Description, DefaultLDF.Description ) As Description
    ,  Coalesce( SpecificLDF.SomeOtherText, DefaultLDF.SomeOtherText ) As SomeOtherText
    ,  ...
From MainObjectTable As M
    Left Join RankedLanguages As SpecificLDF
        On SpecificLDF.MainObjectTable_ID = M.ID
            And SpecifcLDF.Language_ID = @languageId
            And SpecifcLDF.Rnk = 1

    Left Join RankedLanguages As DefaultLDF
        On DefaultLDF.MainObjectTable_ID = M.ID
            And DefaultLDF.Language_ID = @defaultLanguageId
            And DefaultLDF.Rnk = 1

Where M.ID = @MainObjectTableID
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas-I guess there's no magic inbuilt function for this and whatever my SPROC solution I'm always going to have to check for both languages.  This is really what I wanted clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  SELECT MainObjectTable.VariousColumns, 
        COALESCE(PrefLang.Description,Fallback.Description,'Not Found Desc') 
                 as Description,
        COALESCE(PrefLang.SomeOtherText,FallBack.SomeOtherText,'Not found') 
                 as SomeOtherText
    FROM MainObjectTable    
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT TOP 1 pl.Description,pl.SomeOtherText
                  FROM LanguageDependantField1 pl
              WHERE pl.MainObjectTable_ID = MainObjectTable.ID 
                AND pl.Language_ID = @language
              ORDER BY 
                 pl.[Default], pl.CreatedDate DESC) 
    PrefLang ON 1=1
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT TOP 1 fb.Description,fb.SomeOtherText
                  FROM LanguageDependantField1 fb
              WHERE fb.MainObjectTable_ID = MainObjectTable.ID 
                AND fb.Language_ID = @fallbackLanguageID
          ORDER BY 
                 fb.[Default], fb.CreatedDate DESC) 
    Fallback ON 1=1

    WHERE 
         MainObjectTable.ID = @MainObjectTableID
```

Basically, make two queries, one to the preferred language and one to English (Default).  Use the LEFT JOIN, so if the first one isn't found, the second query is used...

I don't have your actual tables, so there might be a syntax error in above, but hope it gives you the concept you want to try...

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. `pl.MainObjectTable_ID = MainObjectTable.ID` will fail because you cannot reference the outer table from within a derived table.